# Database column with default constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a database column like this:

```
Alter table tablename
add column columnname null
add constraint df_columnname default 0
```

After executing above SQL, the new column is added to table with null values.

Does the `constraint df_cloumnname` have no meaning here?

Please clarify on this..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your column is **nullable**, then adding it with a default constraint has no impact - it can be null, and will remain null. The `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` in that case only applies to **new rows** that are being added (and that do not explicitly specify a value for your column).

If your column were **NOT NULL**, then the default constraint would be applied right away.

If you're using **SQL Server** (you didn't specify clearly enough - `SQL` is the **query language** - but not a database product...), and you want a nullable column witha  default constraint and you want the value to be applied to the existing rows, use this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename
ADD columnname NULL
  CONSTRAINT df_columnname DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES
```

Add the `WITH VALUES` to your command and you should get the desired result.

Comment: @Avinash: then you should always use the `sql-server` tag for your questions.

Comment: I did not under stood , WITH values option..can you please clarify..In my database, i am have an existing table with database columns nullable and also have a default constaint..I am Confused!!!

Comment: The database column nullable , after making an entry into table , the value stored for that column is the default value specified in the constraint and not null

Comment: @Avinash: as you saw: just adding a nullable column with a default constraint does **not** add the values to the existing rows; when you use `WITH VALUES`, for each of the existing rows, the defined default values will be inserted.